# what does coursier.mainJar property set to in `coursier` launcher

Tags: scala

it is suggested if the standalone jar cannot be fetched through the coursier script, one can manually download the jar, and kick off the program with the following,

`java -cp coursier-cli_2.11-1.0.1-standalone.jar coursier.cli.Coursier launch`

However the launcher script seems to set the system property `coursier.mainJar` too, while the above direct call does not. Does anybody what that is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to make some changes to let the program accept the proxy username and password to run,
https://github.com/shengc/jupyter-scala